# Envío de valores nulos a SQL Server desde ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, sql-server-2008

En mi base de datos tengo una tabla con valores nulos. Sin embargo, al momento de realizar un envío desde Visual Studio me da el error:

> {"Procedure or function 'sp_ApoyoCud' expects parameter '@enunciado', which was not supplied."}

El parámetro `@enunciado` está declarado como `nvarchar` y acepta nulos, en Visual está como `String`.

En la entidad le especifico que acepte nulos:

```
public class Apoyo
{
    public  int idApoyo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<string> enunciado { get; set; }
    public Nullable<string> link { get; set; }
    public Nullable<string> imagenUrl { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase imagenImagen { get; set; }

}
```

pero me da este error:

> Error  1   El tipo 'string' debe ser un tipo de valor distinto de null para poder utilizarlo como parámetro 'T' en el tipo o método genérico 'System.Nullable'

Comment: Hola Bryan. Para poder ayudarte, necesitas compartir el código en cuestión.

Comment: Hola Bryan, bienvenido a [es.so], como bien comenta sstan, ¿podrías compartirnos el código con el que tienes el problema? Esto para saber más a detalle lo que falla y no caer en especulación. De igual forma, te recomiendo tomar el [tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), así como ir al [centro de ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para saber cómo preguntar y saber algunas reglas del sitio :D

Comment: El hecho de que la tabla acepte nulos, no quiere decir que no se deban definir los parámetros en VS, el propio compilador te lo esta indicando, debes incluir el parametro @enunciado con un valor nulo, dbnull.value.

Comment: Es necesario que [creas un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Siendo directos, se necesita: **La definición de tu procedimiento almacenado** `sp_ApoyoCud`, el código como invocas a dicho procedimiento. Asimismo, propongo cerrar tu pregunta porque no está clara tu pregunta.

Comment: brother, para ayudarte, completa tu código: agrega el procedimiento almacenado y los métodos de las clases que llamas :D

Comment: Has `Nullable` tu campo... para los strings es algo como `Nullable<String> campo;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El primer error me parece que no es problema de tu código, sino de tu base de datos.

Prueba a modificar el procedimiento almacenado y a la hora de declarar los parámetros define un valor por default para que no te rechace la petición en caso de no mandarlo:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_ApoyoCud @enunciado = '', ...
```

De esta manera le indicas al SGBD que de no recibir el parámetro `@enunciado` puede continuar tomándolo como un texto sin valor `''`.

Comment: amigo, muchas gracias. tu idea me ayudo a resolver mi problema

Answer (score 2):

Vamos por partes, la presente respuesta está limitada con respecto al código que has puesto en tu pregunta.

`System.String` es una referencia que sí puede ser "nullable".

`Nullable<T>` y el signo de pregunta `?` son para valores del tipo Int32, Double, DateTime, entre otros.

Sabiendo esto, reemplaza tu código por lo siguiente:

```
public string enunciado { get; set; }
public string link { get; set; }
public string imagenUrl { get; set; }
```

En segundo lugar, revisa mediante un breakpoint que el valor de "enunciado" sea el que estás esperando.

Comment: gracias por sugerir. de la manera que me indicas es como tenia el código al inicio, le puse el nullable por que tenia entendido que se necesitaba especificar, pero ahora se que string no lo necesita.

Answer (score 0):

El error lo que dice es que estás invocando a sp_ApoyoCud sin pasarle el parámetro @enunciado, seguramente no tiene un valor default, por lo que es necesario usarlo, eventualmente podés pasarle un valor NULL, por ejemplo así:

```
EXEC sp_ApoyoCud @enunciado = NULL
```

Luego internamente en el Sp, hay que considerar este valor, por ejemplo si lo estás usando en un filtro no alcanza con hacer:

```
WHERE Enunciado = @enunciado
```

Esto justamente falla con el NULL, lo que se puede hacer

```
WHERE (@enunciado IS NULL OR Enunciado = @enunciado)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo cambiaría un poco tu código. Primero tu clase la pondría como:

```
public class Apoyo
{
    public  int idApoyo { get; set; }
    public string enunciado { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string imagenUrl { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase imagenImagen { get; set; }

}
```

y al momento de llamar al sp lo valido los parametros de esta forma:

```
       if (link != "")           
          cmd.Parameters["@link"].Value = link ;           
       else
          cmd.Parameters["@link"].Value = DBNull.Value;
```